# What is the difference between the broadcom-sta and bcmwl packages?

Tags: broadcom

Both lots of source packages describe themselves as the Broadcom STA driver.  So what's the difference and what should be used?

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta

Comment: Broadcom-sta is the package used by Jockey, the "Additional Drivers" dialog in Ubuntu. I know of no other difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm a bit surprised that Jockey would install Broadcom-sta - what release is this under and do you know whether it is the source/common packages or dkms?  After my own research I think bcmwl-kernel-source is the Ubuntu package and Broadcom-sta is the Debian package(s).  The bcmwl package depends on the linux headers packages (so they are automatically installed), but the Broadcom-sta packages don't so a user would have to manually install them.